# Can regex captures be used in search and replace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of C++ code lines that looks like this:

```
foo.bar("abc");
foo.bar("xyz123");
```

And I want to update each `foo.bar` call to be wrapped with another function:

```
Helper::fixup(foo.bar("abc"));
Helper::fixup(foo.bar("xyz123"));
```

I can easily hit CTRL+H to start a search and replace within the open source file with these search and replace rules:

```
 search: foo.bar("
replace: Helper.fixup(foo.bar("
```

And that fixes the prefix portion, but doesn't add the extra closing parentheses at the end.

What I want to do:

```
 search: (?<capture>foo\.bar\(".*\))
replace: Helper.fixup\(<content of "capture" section>\)
```

Is this possible with the vscode editor for search and replace feature?

For what it's worth, the search expression with the named capture works when the search box is in regex mode and finds the matching expressions in the code file.  But I can't figure out how to designate the capture to be part of the replacement string.